# I cannot open the description of jobs on spark webui

Tags: apache-spark, ganglia

[image]

I am new to Spark. When I trying to install ganglia on my cluster, I find there is something wrong with spark webui. As the above image shows, the format of Spark webui looks strange and I cannot open the hyperlink of description of jobs! I googled it but find nothing helpful.

======update===============

I have checked chrome's developer console and find there are 3 js errors. But I don't know how to fix them.

[image]

Comment: Which webui are looking at the 4040 or the 8080?

Comment: It's 4040. And I find it is caused by 3 js errors. But I don't know how to fix them.

Comment: Are you sure spark is still up?, the 4040 is alive only then.

Comment: Yes. I can see the progress bar on 4040.

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce the problem - can't help you